# How to check if new email exist when changing email

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've implemented flow that enables logged in user to modify their email address. I've email validation process, which occurs after a verification code is sent to the new email address and the user enters that code. In this step, when user enters the code and click verify, I want to check if user's desired email address already exists in the system and raise error. However, the current logic isn't functioning as expected.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserExistUsingEmailCheck">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailObjectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
<DisplayControl Id="ChangeEmailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <!-- Display control to prompt for a email and verify it by sending code to it. -->
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailVerificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateEmailOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ChangeEmailOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserExistUsingEmailCheck" ContinueOnError="false" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyEmailOtp" >
                <Preconditions>
                  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                      <Value>emailObjectId</Value>
                      <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWriteEmailUsingObjectId">
          <DisplayName>Update email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">There is another user with this email address</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="ChangeEmailVerificationControl" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserExistUsingEmailCheck" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteEmailUsingObjectId" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SendEmailChangeEvent" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AAD-UserExistUsingEmailCheck` technical profile, add the following Metadata item: `<Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>`

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserExistUsingEmailCheck">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailObjectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

You can localise the message shown to the user by adding the Metadata item `Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">You are already registered, please press the back button and sign in instead.</Item>` or using [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization) with `<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">The account you are trying to create already exists, please sign-in.</LocalizedString>`

The only thing to note is that the user must hit the continue button after verifying the email address, but you could remove this requirement by using JavaScript to click continue after the email is verified by the display control.

Comment: I had to add `<ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteEmailUsingObjectId" ContinueOnError="false" >` to the `VerifyCode` action to raise error.  But now the issue is that if the user enters the same email they loggedin with, it continues with the validation, instead of raising error.